# how to integrate git on mplab.x

Tags: git, mplab

I'm currently using MPLABX IDE v2.10 and GIT is missing. I tried to implement git plugin available on this link: http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/

But there is not a GIT plugin for the MPLABX IDE that is based on NetBeans 7.x

Anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is this plugin available : nbgit-0.4-netbeans-6.9.nbm

Installation by the plugin manager of MPLABX works ok
Download link is : https://code.google.com/p/nbgit/downloads/list?q=0.4

We can also found example of using git in MPLABX in this blog : http://www.bwiegmann.de/index.php/en/home/29-blog/blog-en/47-git-in-mplab-x-2

It seems to work, on MPLABX 2.10